# How to remove CSS styling from text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fromhtml

I am getting `HTML` text from a web service. I removed the `HTML` by using following code, but `CSS` code is still there.

**Code**

```
TextView tvNews;
tvNews.setText(Html.fromHtml(extractContent));    
tvNews = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_newsView);
tvNews.setText(Html.fromHtml(extractContent));
```

The above code removed the `HTML`, but `CSS` code is still there.

**CSS Code**

```
   <style>\nbody {\n    background-color: #ffffff;\n}\ntd\n{\npadding:5px;
\ncellpadding:25px;\n}\nthead th\n{\npadding:5px;\ncellpadding:25px;
\n}\n<\/style>\n<p><strong>My TEXT<\/strong> \u2013
```

Kindly guide me how to remove `CSS` code from feed and put it into `textView`

Comment: have you solved your problem can you share please?

Comment: @WaleedAsim :  Use `jsoup` library

Comment: would you like to share?
because i'm using Jsoup but didnt work in my recyclerView Adapter

Comment: @WaleedAsim : you can also do following; If you are using webview ;
 ` tvNews.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "Your Data ", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
 tvNews.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: i want to remove from html  css from text not from webview. webview has loadDatawithBaseUrl method. its all about webView you wrote

Comment: @WaleedAsim : better to change you approach then. I am using web view

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for removing the html tags from html then use Jsoup( http://jsoup.org)

```
 String textFromHtml = Jsoup.parse(MY_HTML_STRING_HERE).text();
 TextView desc = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.description);
 desc.setText(textFromHtml);
```

or for WebView

You can use this jquery method to get only text

```
var myContent = '<div id="test">Hello <span>world!</span></div>';

alert($(myContent).text());
```

That results in hello world.

http://jsfiddle.net/D2tEf/ for an example

Comment: Can i use this in Android?